# Nuget installs wrong package version

Tags: version, nuget, signalr

SignalR version 1.0.0 is out, but I want to install the old version 1.0.0-rc1.

I used [this command](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/1.0.0-rc1) but NuGet seems to ignore the version flag and install 1.0.0 anyway.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.0.0-rc1 -Pre
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS (≥ 1.0.0-rc1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery (≥ 1.6.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb (≥ 1.0.0-rc1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin (≥ 1.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core (≥ 1.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.11)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Owin (≥ 1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (≥ 1.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 1.0.0-rc1' already installed.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 1.0.0-rc1' to GeoMVC.
```

The last line claims that 1.0.0-rc1 was successfully installed, but clearly NuGet is resolving dependencies for 1.0.0 rather than 1.0.0-rc1.  When I look at the references in my project, they are version 1.0.0.

I've tried uninstalling the package using `uninstall-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -force` and then reinstalling it.  Same as above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Great question by the way.  Spurs some talks on our end for ensuring that we make strict dependencies for rc versions etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because the Dependencies on the SignalR 1.0.0-rc2 all are >= 1.0.0-rc2 so when it auto resolves the packages it resolves them to be the rtw version.

There's no magic or easy way to fix this but a work around is to install the packages from the base up.  For example install the Core components first and then work your way up the chain.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS -Version 1.0.0-rc2 -Pre  
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 1.0.0-rc2 -Pre  
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core -Version 1.0.0-rc2 -Pre  
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin -Version 1.0.0-rc2 -Pre  
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb -Version 1.0.0-rc2 -Pre  
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR-Version 1.0.0-rc2 -Pre
```

I believe this is all correct.  Let me know if I forgot something.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR is a meta-package that includes all the various SignalR packages.  When it resolves its dependencies, it uses a >= constraint on their versions instead of a == constraint, so NuGet goes ahead and gets the latest versions.